# What is the difference between \startlua and \startluacode?

Tags: context, context-mkiv

Is there any difference between `\startlua` and `\startluacode`? The commands seem to have a similar purpose, but I have found some code does compile properly if the wrong one is chosen. When is one used? When is the other?

Comment: Can you provide an example where `startlua` works and `startluacode` not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The difference are the catcodes. `\startlua` uses TeX catcodes, `startluacode` uses Lua catcodes. Two examples:

```
\starttext

\startlua
-- fails both
-- context("Foo %Bar")
-- %context("Foo \n Bar")
\stoplua

\startluacode
-- prints Foo
-- context("Foo %Bar")

-- prints Foo Bar
context("Foo \n Bar")
\stopluacode

\stoptext
```

For more information you can have a look at the source file `luat-ini.mkiv`.